# once posted setting value to null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my jQuery code

```
$('.chat_bar_message_input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var message_body = $('.chat_bar_message_input').val();
        $.post("assets/scripts/chat/message_parse.php", {message: message_body}, function(data) {
alert(data);
        })
        $('.chat_bar_message_input').val("")
    }
});
```

and here's the HTML

```
<textarea class ="chat_bar_message_input"></textarea>
```

The code is for a chat bar application I am working on, and this code is supposed to set the value of the textarea to null when it is submitted. However, because it runs the code when the enter button is pressed it runs the code, clears the value of the textarea then adds the line break in the textarea. How can I prevent this?

All help is much apreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` which will stop the browser action to enter new line.

you can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was some kind of code to stop the default action and thought it would solve this issue but I didn't know what to look for :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Javascript's REGEX to remove trailing whitespace?

For example:

```
message_body = message_body.replace(/\s+$/, '');
```

The `\s` will look for whitespace and new line characters, and the `$` searches at the end only.

References:
http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-format.php and
http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Answer (score 1):

If you `return false` also it will prevent the default behavior. Try this

```
$('.chat_bar_message_input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       var message_body = $('.chat_bar_message_input').val();
        $.post("assets/scripts/chat/message_parse.php", {message: message_body}, function(data) {
alert(data);
        })
        $('.chat_bar_message_input').val("")
      return false;
    }
});
```